# Properties not found with Spring PropertySource

Tags: java, spring, properties, annotations, filenotfoundexception

Config

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath*:properties/test-database.properties")
})
public class DataSourceConfiguration {//...
}
```

Prop location

```
D:\Projects\opti\dao\src\main\resources\properties\test-database.properties
```

D:\Projects\opti\dao\src\main\resources marked as resource folder.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid this kind of problem the issue is to set the **jboss.server.config.dir** in *VM arguments* like that :

```
-Djboss.server.config.dir="[jboss_repository]/server/[default-all-standard-standalone]/conf" –server
```

and u set PropertySource like this :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/file.properties")
```

**Or** you set ur property like that

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
```

When executed, properties will be imported from the **application.properties**
 file, located in the classpath root.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear well the your problem considering the details of your question, but a typical problem whit @PropertySource is that yuo have configure a spring bean for manage the properties. In old years in which xml was the best way for configure Spring you used a namespace configuration that configure a spring bean for use proeprties in your bean, mainly with @Value. In java config for benefit of same behaviour you have configure a bean like belove:

```
@Bean
public static PlaceholderConfigurerSupport propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
       return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
   }
```

I hope that this can help you

Comment: It is strange, but with Guava Resources.getResource("/properties/test-database.properties") file is not found to.

Comment: I think, it because of gradle, need to think.

Comment: it is clear because with / you have a relative file path you have without / like this:  Resources.getResource("properties/test-database.properties")